# why isn't strlen working?

Tags: php, strlen

```
strlen($_POST["link"]) > 5 ? $link = $_POST["link"] : $errormsg .= "Please enter a link for the article.<br />";
strlen($_POST["img_link"]) > 5 ? $img_link = $_POST["img_link"] : $errormsg .= "Please enter a image link for the article.<br />";
echo $errormsg;
```

the error message is always empty, no matter what the input is.

Comment: Have you tried it without ternary if?

Comment: hve you tried replacing $_POST['link'] with something like and 'example' string, to see whether it works or not ? On first sight, i can't see something weird going on

Comment: using if statement would be more clear and appropriated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ternary operator, but in the same time, you are making spaghetti out of your error messages. Doesn't go that way :)

```
if(strlen($_POST["link"]) > 5){
    $link = $_POST["link"];
}else{
    $errors[] = "Please enter a link for the article.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
strlen($_POST["link"]) > 5 ? ($link = $_POST["link"]) : ($errormsg .= "Please enter a link for the article.<br />");
strlen($_POST["img_link"]) > 5 ? ($img_link = $_POST["img_link"]) : ($errormsg .= "Please enter a image link for the article.<br />");
echo $errormsg;
```

The ternary operator [has a higher precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than the assignment operator.